# do we need to define all Models in Fluent Api?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

In .Net Tutorial (in udemy and in some sites) I saw they declare the Fluent API for defining the relationship between Models.

I tried to create models and not define relationship in Fluent API, it seems the migrations work and I checked on Mysql foreign key was well defined as well.

I just need to know, when we really need to define the relationship between models with Fluent API (`OnModelCreating`)

My Models:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CRSApp.API.Models
{
    public class UserGroup
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string GroupName { get; set; }

        ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

        ICollection<UserGroupDetail> Details {get; set;}
    }
}


namespace CRSApp.API.Models
{
    public class UserGroupDetail
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UserGroupId { get; set; }
        public int ModuleComponentId { get; set; }

        public UserGroup UserGroup { get; set; }
        public ModuleComponent ModuleComponent { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: EF will use convetions to generate the "releations", if you don't declare them explicetly, take a look https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when we really need to define the relationship between models with Fluent API

When you don't adhere to conventions, or when your intended usage lies outside these conventions.

The modelbuilder can infer a lot of commonly used intentions, but for example a non-optional one-to-one relation needs to be defined using attributes or fluent configuration.